# How to get a path's outline?

Tags: path, outline

I have some point like below：

1. [[1,4],[2,8]]
2. [[5,4],[3,8],[5,4]]

Then I make a line (lat's say the width is 2) , I want to get the line's outline(path), see the Example Image's black line.

In one world, I have wall corner's coordinate, I want to figure out the outline's path of the wall(In the Example image, the red part is the coordinate, and the black lines are what I want to get )

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWRMd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar project. I decided to use vectors to get the parallel lines along the path by getting the cross product of the UP vector and the vector of points 1 to 2 which will get you a vector that is pointing away from the line that you can use to get the begin and end point of the parallel line

```
CVec3 a, v1, v2, zero, up(0, 1.0f, 0);
zero.set(0,0,0);

v1.sub(points[1], points[0]);
v2.sub(points[2], points[1]);
a.crossProduct(up, v1);
a.normalise();

result[0] = result[1] = a;
result[0].mult(wallwidth).add(points[0]);
result[1].mult(-wallwidth).add(points[0]);
result[2].set(result[0]).add(v1);
result[3].set(result[1]).add(v1);
```

result[0] to result[2] is line in one side while result[1] to result[3] will be the other one. I haven't figure out how to connect the lines so they make corner without deforming the line width